# Does NFT name need to be base16 encoded in metadata.json file? How can I verify it was registered successfuly including the json?

Tags: nft, testnet

The guide for NFT minting is quite outdate and not working at this moment - https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting-nfts/ because since recent version of cardano-cli all token names must be base16 encoded (I wasn't able to use non-encoded names at least).

So I was following this guide completely and managed to register the NFT on testnet when I base16 encoded the token name in CLI, but I don't seem to be able to verify if it was actually correctly registered. Most of NFT browsers don't work with testnet and when using testnet cardanoscan I only see the name of token, but nothing else - no metadata, no IPFS picture, not even description, just the decrypted base16 name, which makes me feel like the metadata either didn't register, or they mismatch the token name?

How can I verify if testnet token was properly registered? How can I query metadata for a token in certain address? Do I need to base16 encode the token name in metadata.json?

Comment: Please note that the guide was updated with this pull request: https://github.com/cardano-foundation/developer-portal/pull/428/files

Comment: it would be useful if manual also contained the actual command `echo -n $NAME | base16` explaining how you can get the encoded name

Comment: I agree, can you do a pull request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I verify if testnet token was properly registered?

When you mint your NFT, you're able to check the `Mint transactions` tab in cardanoscan/testnet.cardanoscan. For example, the following tokens were minted in one transaction:

- https://testnet.cardanoscan.io/token/62264a920c007b90d6b950f34245d42c66f6fd23c1547f1662bfa54743617264616e6f7263313636

Then you can go to the Transaction in the `Mint transactions` and you will find `Metadata` tab. There should be your Metadata for `721`.

If nothing is displayed there, it's because your minting process has something wrong.

> How can I query metadata for a token in certain address?

You can use [blockfrost](https://blockfrost.io/) to query an specific asset and get the metadata. For example, to query this token: https://testnet.cardanoscan.io/token/62264a920c007b90d6b950f34245d42c66f6fd23c1547f1662bfa54743617264616e6f726331363239

You can use:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://cardano-testnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/assets/62264a920c007b90d6b950f34245d42c66f6fd23c1547f1662bfa54743617264616e6f726331363239' \
--header 'project_id: <your_project_id>'
```

And you will get this:

```
{
    "asset": "62264a920c007b90d6b950f34245d42c66f6fd23c1547f1662bfa54743617264616e6f726331363239",
    "policy_id": "62264a920c007b90d6b950f34245d42c66f6fd23c1547f1662bfa547",
    "asset_name": "43617264616e6f726331363239",
    "fingerprint": "asset1gljzhfsaqvep43gjez0t4hj3fj3jwv455cw0e4",
    "quantity": "1",
    "initial_mint_tx_hash": "9262943a49cc3dca038e907e0e0a9f3ac55ef60a2d3032cab45bfee1ff4d4e37",
    "mint_or_burn_count": 1,
    "onchain_metadata": {
        "name": "Cardanorc1629",
        "image": "ipfs://Qme3iiz4QWXo48xusytQ2u2E7RpnNJdLjGpUStcb6aYWtn",
        "id": 1629,
        "properties": {
            "Eye": "Agate",
            "Head": "No Head Accessory3",
            "Race": "Margog",
            "Mouth": "No Trait",
            "Earring": "No Earring 1",
            "Background": "Brown",
            "Special_Skin": "None",
            "Body_Accessory": "No Armor2",
            "Special_Mouth_Trait": "Gold Side Tooth"
        },
        "description": "Cardanorcs - The Beginning"
    },
    "metadata": null
}
```

> Do I need to base16 encode the token name in metadata.json?

No, you don't need it.

---

Some additional points to consider:

- Make sure you're using the right policyId in your metadata and your minting process
- You can verify your metadata from here: https://pool.pm/test/metadata

Comment: what do I replace your_project_id with? that curl returns `{"status_code":403,"error":"Forbidden"`

Comment: ok seems account on blockfrost was needed, there is a free plan, now I can see that the NFT was probably registered properly, although using cardanoscan it's barely visible as it doesn't render IPFS image

Comment: Yes, you need a blockfrost account. Sure, cardanoscan only works to check the metadata , not to render IPFS. Anyway, you can use the blockfrost gateway to check that.