# NFT Minting without Metadata

Tags: nft, minting

I hope all is well and everyone had a great holiday season. I am having an issue minting NFT's from the CLI they appear to be minting without metadata, even though I am referring to the fully populated metadata.json file used. All variables are correct ($variables are correct) Can anyone toss me a bone at what I'm doing wrong? The NFT does actually mint, just minus all metadata and thus no picture or details about the NFT.

My Minting Command =

```
cardano-cli transaction build \
--mainnet \
--alonzo-era \
--tx-in $txhash#$txix \
--tx-out $nftwallet+$output+"$tokenamount $policyid.$tokenname" \
--change-address $address \
--mint="$tokenamount $policyid.$tokenname" \
--minting-script-file $script \
--metadata-json-file metadata.json \
--invalid-hereafter $slotnumber \
--witness-override 2 \
--out-file matx.raw
```

Metadata file -

```
{
"721": {
"HIDDEN": {
"HIDDEN": {
"name": "NFT NAME HERE",
"image": "ipfs://IPFSLINKHERE",
"mediaType": "image/png",
"description": "DESCRIPTION HERE",
"files": [
{
"name": "PIC NAME HERE",
"mediaType": "image/png",
"src": "ipfs://IPFS LINK HERE"
}
]
}
},
"version": "1.0"
}
}
```

Comment: Please, take a look on this answer: https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/4882/1231

Comment: Could you please include the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely because your token name doesnt match between the CLI and the metadata.json file. Hard to say since you've hidden them...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like more of a data issue within the metadata json, rather then a problem in the transaction format.

It looks like you're following the https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting-nfts/

Please note that the `--mint="$tokenamount $policyid.$tokenname" \` `$policyid` and `$tokenname`, have to match the two `HIDDEN` fields in the metadata.json

Furthermore, the digital asset (eg. the image/audio/video/whatever) needs to be in a IPFS server. Sometimes some IPFS services are slow at serving/propagating the asset, so a workaround, is to create an account on pinata.cloud and load your asset there. Then you're sure everything is fine.

For further help, can you share a minting transaction hash? This way we can inspect the tx and tell you exactly whats wrong.

If you want to do a test, you can use new policy/image whatever, so you won't share private stuff.

Thanks and good luck

Answer (score 0):

Your metadata file is not structured correctly. Please check [CIP 25 - NFT Metadata Standard](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip25/).

```
{
  "721": {
    "<policy_id>" {
       ...
```